# LNK errors during built project with libcurl added

Tags: visual-studio-2012, libcurl, lnk2019, lnk2001, lnk2005

I've solved for 2 weeks how to build libcurl project. Finally today I managed it, I followed http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/Using-libcurl-with-SSH-support-in-Visual-Studio-2010.pdf but after I wanted to add libcurl to my own project, it throws lot of LNK errors. So here is code my own project, where I want to add libcurl. It's only for downloading file from url:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "DlData.h"
    #include "curl.h"

    //#define CURL_STATICLIB  

//#pragma comment(lib, "libcurld") 
//#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32") 
//#pragma comment(lib, "Wldap32.lib")


size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DlData test;
    test.PrintMsg("this is test!");
    test.WaitForClick();

    //Part for download file
    CURL *curl;
    ofstream fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1415/E0.csv";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\Users\\zdenik\\Documents\\GitProjects\\Predictor\\Files\\";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        fp.open(outfilename);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fp.close();
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I set my project properties properly (C/C++ - General, Preprocessor, Linker - General, Input) and want to build it as application - exe file. So far I everything went well and I was able to create libcurld.lib which I added to linker in my project properties. After I built it, it throws a lot of LNK errors and it looks like there is no lib added. Here is output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Predictor, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  Main.cpp
1>  DlData.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _calloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgcalloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgfree.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrealloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memmove.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strchr already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strchr.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strncmp already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strncmp.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strrchr already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strrchr.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fclose already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fclose.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fopen already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fopen.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __strtoi64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __errno already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _tolower already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(tolower.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fseek already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fseek.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _ftell already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(ftell.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isalpha already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isxdigit already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fwrite already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fwrite.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strtoul already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isdigit already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fputc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fputc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _sprintf already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isspace already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _memchr already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memchr.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isalnum already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(atox.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __lseeki64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(lseeki64.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _getenv already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(getenv.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isupper already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _islower already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isprint already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isgraph already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __read already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(read.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __write already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(write.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __strnicmp already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strnicmp.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __close already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(close.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) : error LNK2005: __open already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(open.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>libcurld.lib(easy.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8 referenced in function _win32_init
1>libcurld.lib(telnet.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8
1>libcurld.lib(easy.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSACleanup@0 referenced in function _win32_cleanup
1>libcurld.lib(telnet.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSACleanup@0
1>libcurld.lib(misc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>libcurld.lib(telnet.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0 referenced in function _printsub
1>libcurld.lib(tftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>libcurld.lib(ftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>libcurld.lib(asyn-thread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>libcurld.lib(select.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>libcurld.lib(sendf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>libcurld.lib(connect.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>libcurld.lib(global.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf referenced in function _libssh2_init
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
...

1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_load_error_strings referenced in function _Curl_ossl_init
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_SESSION_free referenced in function _Curl_ossl_session_free
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_set_session referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_peer_certificate referenced in function _servercert
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_peer_cert_chain referenced in function _verifystatus
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_verify referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb referenced in function _cert_stuff
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata referenced in function _cert_stuff
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_check_private_key referenced in function _cert_stuff
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_new referenced in function _cert_stuff
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_free referenced in function _Curl_ossl_close
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_connect referenced in function _ossl_connect_step2
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_read referenced in function _Curl_ossl_shutdown
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_peek referenced in function _Curl_ossl_check_cxn
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_write referenced in function _ossl_send
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_ctrl referenced in function _verifystatus
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_ctrl referenced in function _ossl_connect_step1
1>libcurld.lib(openssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_get_error referenced in function _Curl_ossl_shutdown
...

1>C:\Users\zdenik\Documents\GitProjects\Predictor\Debug\Predictor.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 213 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My question is simple. What could be wrong with my project properties settings or how to set libcurld.lib properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally done it. I downloaded precompiled version of libcurl for Windows 32bit, but before I compiled code, I noticed there is error in char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\Users\zdenik\Documents\GitProjects\Predictor\Files\" row. It is needed to add name of the file at the end of the path string - C:\Users\zdenik\Documents\GitProjects\Predictor\Files\file.csv e.g. It would not cause compile error but app would crash after it's triggering.

After that code compiled successfully.